# Plot a histogram such that bar heights sum to 1 (probability)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

I'd like to plot a normalized histogram from a vector using `matplotlib`.  I tried the following:

```
plt.hist(myarray, normed=True)
```

as well as:

```
plt.hist(myarray, normed=1)
```

but neither option produces a y-axis from [0, 1] such that the bar heights of the histogram sum to 1.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It would be more helpful if you posed a more complete working (or in this case non-working) example.

I tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(1000)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
n, bins, rectangles = ax.hist(x, 50, density=True)
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.show()
```

This will indeed produce a bar-chart histogram with a y-axis that goes from `[0,1]`.

Further, as per the `hist` documentation (i.e. `ax.hist?` from `ipython`), I think the sum is fine too:

```
*normed*:
If *True*, the first element of the return tuple will
be the counts normalized to form a probability density, i.e.,
``n/(len(x)*dbin)``.  In a probability density, the integral of
the histogram should be 1; you can verify that with a
trapezoidal integration of the probability density function::

    pdf, bins, patches = ax.hist(...)
    print np.sum(pdf * np.diff(bins))
```

Giving this a try after the commands above:

```
np.sum(n * np.diff(bins))
```

I get a return value of `1.0` as expected.  Remember that `normed=True` doesn't mean that the sum of the value at each bar will be unity, but rather than the integral over the bars is unity.  In my case `np.sum(n)` returned approx `7.2767`.

Comment: Yep, that's a probability density graph, I think he wants a probability mass graph.

Answer (score 232):

If you want the sum of all bars to be equal unity, weight each bin by the total number of values:

```
weights = np.ones_like(myarray) / len(myarray)
plt.hist(myarray, weights=weights)
```

Note for Python 2.x: add casting to `float()` for one of the operators of the division as otherwise you would end up with zeros due to integer division

Answer (score 23):

I know this answer is too late considering the question is dated 2010 but I came across this question as I was facing a similar problem myself. As already stated in the answer, normed=True means that the total area under the histogram is equal to 1 but the sum of heights is not equal to 1. However, I wanted to, for convenience of physical interpretation of a histogram, make one with sum of heights equal to 1.

I found a hint in the following question - [Python: Histogram with area normalized to something other than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036298/python-histogram-with-area-normalized-to-something-other-than-1)

But I was not able to find a way of making bars mimic the histtype="step" feature hist(). This diverted me to : [Matplotlib - Stepped histogram with already binned data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297030/matplotlib-stepped-histogram-with-already-binned-data)

If the community finds it acceptable I should like to put forth a solution which synthesises ideas from both the above posts.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Let X be the array whose histogram needs to be plotted.
nx, xbins, ptchs = plt.hist(X, bins=20)
plt.clf() # Get rid of this histogram since not the one we want.

nx_frac = nx/float(len(nx)) # Each bin divided by total number of objects.
width = xbins[1] - xbins[0] # Width of each bin.
x = np.ravel(zip(xbins[:-1], xbins[:-1]+width))
y = np.ravel(zip(nx_frac,nx_frac))

plt.plot(x,y,linestyle="dashed",label="MyLabel")
#... Further formatting.
```

This has worked wonderfully for me though in some cases I have noticed that the left most "bar" or the right most "bar" of the histogram does not close down by touching the lowest point of the Y-axis. In such a case adding an element 0 at the begging or the end of y achieved the necessary result.

Just thought I'd share my experience. Thank you.

Comment: i think you need normed=True as well in plt.hist. Also in Python 3 you have to use list(zip(...)).

Answer (score 15):

Here is another simple solution using `np.histogram()` method.

```
myarray = np.random.random(100)
results, edges = np.histogram(myarray, normed=True)
binWidth = edges[1] - edges[0]
plt.bar(edges[:-1], results*binWidth, binWidth)
```

You can indeed check that the total sums up to 1 with:

```
> print sum(results*binWidth)
1.0
```

Answer (score 9):

- The easiest solution is to use [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html), or [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) with `kind='hist'`, and specify `stat='probability'`

  - **probability**: or **proportion**: normalize such that bar heights sum to 1
  - **density**: normalize such that the total area of the histogram equals 1
  - `data`: [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame), [`numpy.ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy.ndarray), mapping, or sequence
- `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`

  - [Figure-level vs. axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)
  - [seaborn histplot and displot output doesn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68865538/7758804)
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### Imports and Data

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
df = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
```

### `sns.histplot`

- [axes-level plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#axes-level-functions-make-self-contained-plots)

```
# create figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 5))

p = sns.histplot(data=df, x='flipper_length_mm', stat='probability', ax=ax)
```

[image]

### `sns.displot`

- [figure-level plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-functions-own-their-figure)

```py
p = sns.displot(data=df, x='flipper_length_mm', stat='probability', height=4, aspect=1.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since matplotlib 3.0.2, `normed=True` is deprecated. To get the desired output I had to do:

```py
import numpy as np
data=np.random.randn(1000)
bins=np.arange(-3.0,3.0,51)
counts, _ = np.histogram(data,bins=bins)
if density: # equivalent of normed=True
    counts_weighter=counts.sum()
else: # equivalent of normed=False
    counts_weighter=1.0
plt.hist(bins[:-1],bins=bins,weights=counts/counts_weighter)
```

Trying to specify `weights` and `density` simultaneously as arguments to `plt.hist()` did not work for me. If anyone know of a way to get that working without having access to the normed keyword argument then please let me know in the comments and I will delete/modify this answer.

If you want bin centres then don't use `bins[:-1]` which are the bin edges - you need to choose a suitable scheme for how to calculate the centres (which may or may not be trivially derived).