# python - mapping values from a probability mass function to a list of random variables

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

Let's say I have a list of random variables, and I use the histogram function like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = [np.random.randn() for i in range(2**10)]
vals, bin_edges = np.histogram(x, 100)
```

1) How do I efficiently normalize this histogram to become a list representations of a probability mass function?

2) How do I map from this probability mass function to a new list in such a way that I end up with a list where the value at `i` corresponds to the probability of observing `x[i]`?

Comment: Technically the probability of observing `x[i]` is zero. Or -- well, very very small (since we're talking about floating point numbers and not actual real numbers). Do you mean the probability of observing a value in the same bin as `x[i]`?

Comment: My bad, this is of course what I meant.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750276/matplotlib-how-to-convert-a-histogram-to-a-discrete-probability-mass-function