# matplotlib hist() fails (sum of bars not equal one) with Density=True and weights

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, density-plot

I am stuck when working with plt.hist(density=True) although I have set *weights*.
My goal is to retrieve a histogram in which the sum of bars (y-axes) equals 1. It is a deeply discussed issue, however [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498008/pylab-histdata-normed-1-normalization-seems-to-work-incorrect)[[2]](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6357) I can´t derive the right solution. Here is my code:

```py
data = np.array(data).astype("float32")

weights = np.ones_like(data)/float(len(data))

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x=data, density=True, bins=20, color='#0504aa',weights=weights,
                            alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.85)
```

which creates:

[image]

The bars are obviously not summing up to one. Does anybody have a solution for my issue. Maybe it is already posted somewhere, but I am not able to find it?

Greetings

Comment: Use [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) with `stat='probability'`