# Unfilled bar plot in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart

With histograms, there's a simple built-in option `histtype='step'`. How do I make a bar plot in the same style?

Comment: is plt.bar(x, y, color="None") what you want?

Comment: No, because I want to eliminate the vertical lines where bars adjoin each other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297030/matplotlib-stepped-histogram-with-already-binned-data  I found the answer here. This is actually exactly what I wanted to do (use bar plot as histogram), but I didn't find it because I was searching for questions about bar plots.

Answer (score 17):

[adding answer after reading the comments]
Set the optional keyword to be `fill=False` for bar plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(bins[:5], counts[:5], fill=False, width=60)  # <- this is the line

plt.title("Number of nodes with output at timestep")
plt.xlabel("Node count")
plt.ylabel("Timestep (s)")
```

will give:
[image]

Or use `plt.plot` with the keyword `ls='steps'` :

```
plt.plot(bins[-100:], counts[-100:], ls='steps')
plt.title("Number of nodes with output at timestep")
plt.xlabel("Node count")
plt.ylabel("Timestep (s)")
```

[image]

Comment: the second graph was just what I thought he was asking for, and it was what I was looking for too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But can we also avoid the inner edge of the barplot? say that, the vertical line at x=250?

Answer (score 10):

Although OP linked to a post that answered a slightly different question relating to histogram step plots, here is a solution for anyone passing through here who is specifically trying to turn off the face color in `pyplot.bar` bar plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create x coords for the bar plot
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)

# cook up some random bar heights -- exact results may vary :-P
y = np.random.randn(10)
z = np.random.randn(10) * 2

# plot bars with face color off
plt.bar(x-0.2, y, width=0.4, edgecolor='purple', color='None')
plt.bar(x+0.2, z, width=0.4, edgecolor='darkorange', color='None')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that bar edges have settable `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` attributes, such as `linewidth`, `linestyle`, `alpha`, et cetera:

```
plt.bar(x-0.2, y, width=0.4, edgecolor='purple', color='None', 
linewidth=0.75, linestyle='--')
plt.bar(x+0.2, z, width=0.4, edgecolor='darkorange', color='None',
linewidth=1.5, linestyle='-.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I saw you found an answer on [this other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297030/matplotlib-stepped-histogram-with-already-binned-data), nonetheless I have the feeling `matplotlib.pyplot.step` does the job too and is more direct ([see here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html)).

***Edit:*** as requested, some sample code to illustrate usage of `plt.step`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.step(list(range(10)),list(range(5))+list(range(5)))
```

Comment: Please provide code using `matplotlib.pyplot.step` answering the question, as an illustration.