# Matplotlib bar plot remove internal lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have a bar plot with high resolution. Is it possible to have only the border/frame/top line of the plot like in the following ROOT plot without, i.e. without internal lines?

[image: ROOT plot, empty inside]

If I plot with `facecolor='none'` or `'white'`, the plot is slashed by both vertical and horizontal lines:

[image: bar plot color none]

The only way I can get rid of them is to make `edgecolor` and `facecolor` the same, but that's not the look I need...

Comment: Look for example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297030/matplotlib-stepped-histogram-with-already-binned-data. There are several similar questions already answered on SO

Comment: @MyCyclophil Thanks for the answer! I actually finally found it out, the problem was that I was using `plt.bar` instead of `plt.step` thinking that the latter one would be a subtype of the former one. And I was always searching "plot binned data", "histogram remove internal lines", "bar plot only contour" etc. My apologies for making a question solved elsewhere, my solution now is simply `plt.step(xvalues, yvalues)`

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it is hard to find the right key words even though you know exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 13):

Found out the answer: the simplest way to achieve the desired look is to use `plt.step` instead of `plt.bar`, that simple. Feel shame for asking.

[image: step plot]

Answer (score 0):

As referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39372470/python-removing-vertical-bar-lines-from-histogram), you can set `histtype='step'` to remove internal lines. For example,

```
plt.hist(data, histtype='step')
```