# Is there a parameter in matplotlib/pandas to have the Y axis of a histogram as percentage?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to compare two histograms by having the Y axis show the percentage of each column from the overall dataset size instead of an absolute value. Is that possible? I am using Pandas and matplotlib.
Thanks

Comment: Add `normed=True` to your `plt.hist()`.

Comment: Thanks! for some reason that option is not documented at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html#pandas.DataFrame.hist . I am however getting values on the Y axis that are equal and great than 1 (e.g., 1.4). Any idea how that's possible? My intuition was that once normalized the values should be between 0-1.

Comment: The 'normed' kwarg is deprecated, and has been replaced by the 'density'

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The [`density=True`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) (`normed=True` for `matplotlib < 2.2.0`) returns a histogram for which `np.sum(pdf * np.diff(bins))` equals 1. If you want the sum of the histogram to be 1 you can use Numpy's histogram() and normalize the results yourself.

```
x = np.random.randn(30)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,4))

ax[0].hist(x, density=True, color='grey')

hist, bins = np.histogram(x)
ax[1].bar(bins[:-1], hist.astype(np.float32) / hist.sum(), width=(bins[1]-bins[0]), color='grey')

ax[0].set_title('normed=True')
ax[1].set_title('hist = hist / hist.sum()')
```

[image]

Btw: Strange plotting glitch at the first bin of the left plot.

Comment: Could you please explain why pandas behave in this way? I'm little confused. I think most people would go for the sum =1 way.

Comment: **normed** is  Deprecated in matplotlib version 2.2.0 ; use the **density** keyword argument instead.
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html

Comment: The argument `density=True` does not normalize the histogram by the total count. That is, the heights of bars will not sum to 1 (it's rather the height*width that sums to 1 when `density=True`, and this is not what people think when they say normalize the histogram). To normalize histogram, see this https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10398/#issuecomment-366021979 or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16399202

Comment: It's interesting that `normed=True` has been deprecated. It was an intuitive and useful param; I used to use it frequently.

Answer (score 34):

Pandas plotting can accept any extra keyword arguments from the respective matplotlib function. So for completeness from the comments of others here, this is how one would do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,2), columns=list('AB'))

df.hist(density=1)
```

Also, for direct comparison this may be a good way as well:

```
df.plot(kind='hist', density=1, bins=20, stacked=False, alpha=.5)
```

Answer (score 24):

Looks like @CarstenKönig [found the right way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16399202/623735):

```
df.hist(bins=20, weights=np.ones_like(df[df.columns[0]]) * 100. / len(df))
```

Comment: I think the `100` has been missplaced. The correct version is `df.hist(bins=20, weights=np.ones_like(df[df.columns[0]]) * 100. / len(df))`, in case you were thinking of something from 0 to 100.

Comment: Indeed. Good catch! Corrected.

Answer (score 19):

I know this answer is 6 years later but to anyone using density=True (the substitute for the normed=True), this is not doing what you might want to. It will normalize the whole distribution so that the area of the bins is 1. So if you have more bins with a width < 1 you can expect the height to be > 1 (y-axis). If you want to bound your histogram to [0;1] you will have to calculate it yourself.

Comment: Or maybe `df["col"].plot.hist(ax=ax, cumulative=true, 
            weights=list(100*numpy.ones_like(df.index)/len(df.index)))` together with something like `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter('{:.0f}%'.format))`. Not a walk in the park, but could be made to work.

Answer (score 13):

You can simplify the weighting using **np.ones_like()**:

```
df["ColumnName"].plot.hist(weights = np.ones_like(df.index) / len(df.index))
```

- np.ones_like() is okay with the df.index structure
- len(df.index) is faster for large DataFrames

Comment: For some reason that command gave me the error `ValueError: weights should have the same shape as x` (matplotlib 3.0.3). The command that worked for me was `df["ColumnName"].plot.hist(weights = list(np.ones_like(df.index) / len(df.index)))`

Answer (score 5):

I see this is an old question but it shows up on top for some searches, so I think as of 2021 seaborn would be an easy way to do this.

You can do something like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.histplot(df,stat="probability")
```

Comment: This is by far the most straightforward way to achieve what OP asks for. Also, using seaborn is not an unreasonable dependency IMO.

Answer (score 1):

In some scenarios you can adapt with a barplot:

```
tweets_df['label'].value_counts(normalize=True).plot(figsize=(12,12), kind='bar')
```