# Create stacked histogram from unequal length arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to create a stacked histogram.  If I have a single 2-D array, made of three equal length data sets, this is simple.  Code and image below:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# create 3 data sets with 1,000 samples
mu, sigma = 200, 25
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(1000,3)

#Stack the data
plt.figure()
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 30, stacked=True, density = True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, if I try similar code with three data sets of a different length the results are that one histogram covers up another.  Is there any way I can do the stacked histogram with mixed length data sets?

```
##Continued from above
###Now as three separate arrays
x1 = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(990,1)
x2 = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(980,1)
x3 = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(1000,1)

#Stack the data
plt.figure()
plt.hist(x1, bins, stacked=True, density = True)
plt.hist(x2, bins, stacked=True, density = True)
plt.hist(x3, bins, stacked=True, density = True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Well, this is simple.  I just need to put the three arrays in a list.

```
##Continued from above
###Now as three separate arrays
x1 = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(990,1)
x2 = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(980,1)
x3 = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(1000,1)

#Stack the data
plt.figure()
plt.hist([x1,x2,x3], bins, stacked=True, density=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the best way to add a legend for `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` separately?

Comment: plt.hist([x1,x2,x3], bins, stacked=True, color=["red", "blue", "violet"], normed = True); plt.legend({label1: "red", label2: "blue", label3: "violet"})

Comment: This code is throwing error for me: `ValueError: x must have 2 or fewer dimensions`

Answer (score 8):

- If [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is an option, the arrays can be loaded into a dataframe and plotted.
- The benefit of using pandas, is the data is now in a useful format for additional analysis and other plots.
- The following code will create a `list` of `DataFrames` with [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html),  for each array, and then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the arrays together in a list-comprehension.

  - This is a correct way to create a dataframe of arrays that are not equal in length.

    - [SO: Creating dataframe from a dictionary where entries have different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080) has more ways to create dataframes from arrays of unequal length.
  - For equal length arrays, use `df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': x1, 'x2': x2, 'x3': x3})`
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which uses `matplotlib` as the default plot engine.

  - `normed` has been replaced with `density` in `matplotlib`
  - See the `density` parameter in [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) for an explanation of the y-axis values.
- For additional information:

  - [Plot a histogram such that bar heights sum to 1 (probability)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3866520/7758804)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create the uneven arrays
mu, sigma = 200, 25
np.random.seed(365)
x1 = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(990, 1)
x2 = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(980, 1)
x3 = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(1000, 1)

# create the dataframe; enumerate is used to make column names
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a, columns=[f'x{i}']) for i, a in enumerate([x1, x2, x3], 1)], axis=1)

# plot the data
df.plot.hist(stacked=True, bins=30, density=True, figsize=(10, 6), grid=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Do we know what the y-axis decimals refer to?

Comment: @kudo See the `density` parameter in [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) for an explanation of the y-axis values.