# Two ways to join lists in dataframe: as rows and columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists:

```
l1 = ['0a',22,44]
l2 = ['0b',25,55,66]
```

Now I join them so that each list becomes a column of a data frame:

```
import pandas as p
df1 = p.DataFrame(zip(l1,l2))
df1
```

I received the data frame with 3 rows and 2 columns (the value `66` of `l2` is missed). It looks identical to the definition of `ndarray`, which says: "*all columns must have the same number of rows if `ndarray` is passed into dataframe*". But I don't work with `ndarray`!

If, however, I join lists as rows of a data frame, then Python saves `66`:

```
df2 = p.DataFrame([l1,l2])
```

Is there any way to pass lists into dataframe as columns, while saving all values of lists in dataframe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19736406/4080476

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating dataframe from a dictionary where entries have different lengths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `zip` returned list which truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence. So result will be:

```
In [1]: zip(l1,l2)
Out[1]: [('0a', '0b'), (22, 25), (44, 55)]
```

To save value `66` use [izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) from itertools:

```
In [3]: p.DataFrame(list(itertools.izip_longest(l1, l2)))
Out[3]:
      0   1
0    0a  0b
1    22  25
2    44  55
3  None  66
```

Or you can use `map` with `None`. (but map changed in Python 3.x, so that only works in Python 2.x):

```
In [4]: p.DataFrame(map(None, l1, l2))
Out[4]:
      0   1
0    0a  0b
1    22  25
2    44  55
3  None  66
```

Comment: When I run 'pip install itertools' from Command Prompt on Windows, it says 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement itertools <from versions: > No matching distribution found for itertools'. I have Python 2.7. Do you know how to tack this error?

Comment: itertools included in python stdlib. So just import.

Comment: It says No module named stdlib (import stdlib as s)

Comment: `import itertools` instead of  stdlib

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just one final thing. It says TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.

Comment: That's strange. Can you provide traceback and data?

Comment: Indeed it works if I run it from PyCharm IDE, but it fails when I do the same steps in command line ('list' object is not callable). Anyway I'll accept the answer, since the problem with 'list' is different from the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually with your `zip` statement:

```
>>> zip(l1,l2)
[('0a', '0b'), (22, 25), (44, 55)]
```

You can create a Series for each of your lists and then concatenate them to create your data frame.  Here, I use a dictionary comprehension to create the series.  `concat` requires an NDFrame object, so I first create a DataFrame from each of the Series.

```
series = {col_name: values 
          for col_name, values in zip([l1[0], l2[0]], 
                                      [l1[1:], l2[1:]])}

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(s, columns=[col]) for col, s in series.iteritems()], axis=1)
>>> df
   0b  0a
0  25  22
1  55  44
2  66 NaN
```

Also, it appeared that the first element in each list was actually the title to the Series, so I took the liberty of using the first element as the series name.