# Did python or Pandas cache results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ipython

One of the strangest thing i noticed while working with pandas DataFrame. there is a drastic reduction in time to create a DataFrame between 1st and 2nd run of same code.

```
L = list('ABCDEFGH')*20000
min_length = 10000
data_dict = {k: np.random.randint(10, size=min_length) for k in L}
start = time.time()
df = pd.DataFrame({k:v[:min_length] for k,v in data_dict.items()})
print('loop time : ', time.time() - start)
```

Time for 1st run

```
loop time : 0.05926999
```

when i re run the above code

```
loop time : 0.00090622
```

**Can any body explain what just happened?**
**Did pandas or python cache results?**
if you timeit in ipython will get result like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865806/create-a-dataframe-from-dict-of-unequal-length-lists?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Is your program stored in a file?

Comment: yes! is it make any difference?

Comment: I think you should also tag this with iPython. It's interesting because I haven't actually seen that message on `timeit` before so I'm not sure which part it would cache (and no idea how you would trace it), but I can reproduce your result.

Comment: Could it just be the first time the .pyc file hasn't been compiled, and every time after it has? What if you create a 10x loop, but run the code only once?

Comment: @pshep123 I didn't gets u? will you please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

My point was that it may be an issue of the first run taking the time to convert to a .pyc file for run-time. I'm really no expert, and this really isn't an answer, but more of a troubleshooting step.

Try running this and see if the first iteration is materially longer than the subsequent iterations.

```
L = list('ABCDEFGH')*20000
min_length = 10000
data_dict = {k: np.random.randint(10, size=min_length) for k in L} 

for i in range(10):
    start = time.time() 
    df = pd.DataFrame({k:v[:min_length] for k,v in data_dict.items()})
    print('loop time : ', time.time() - start)
```

Comment: I just run the above code. here is my output
`loop time :  0.03665304183959961
loop time :  0.0012547969818115234
loop time :  0.0006182193756103516
.
loop time :  0.0004937648773193359
loop time :  0.0005068778991699219
loop time :  0.0005292892456054688`

Comment: time goes on improving and saturates at some value.

Comment: Wish I could help, but the reasoning behind that is way over my pay-grade!  Good luck in your search.