# how to convert a python dictionary to dataframe when arrays are uneven

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I recently inherited a python file that has a really long dictionary that I would like to convert to a pandas dataframe. I will then take that dataframe and export it to a database with SqlAlchemy to use as a lookup table.

Here is a very small example of what I'm dealing with:

```
example_dict = { 'Foo': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
               'Buzz': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
                'Fizz': ['I', 'J', 'K'],
                'Fuu':['L']}
```

As you probably noticed, the length of each list is not the same.

I would like to convert to a dataframe that resembles

```
Col1    Col2  
A       Foo  
B       Foo  
C       Foo  
D       Foo  
E       Buzz  
F       Buzz  
G       Buzz  
..      ..  
L       Fuu
```

I've tried using
`df = pd.DataFrame(example_dict)` and then using various methods to try and reshape `[df.T, df.melt, df.pivot, df.stack, df.unstack]`

I also tried
`df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(example_dict, orient='index')`

I thought `.explode()` might be a good route because the pandas documentation example is very similar to my problem, but I keep running into errors because the arrays are not of equal size.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Easiest would be to write a loop to convert the dictionary into a list of lists, then convert that to a DF.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create a DataFrame from dict of unequal length lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865806/create-a-dataframe-from-dict-of-unequal-length-lists)

Comment: @deadshot that question is similar, but was not very helpful for my situation. Well at least not at my Python level (beginner). Especially with the NaN values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a series from `example_dict` . Next, use `explode` and `reset_index` to get the dataframe.

```
s = pd.Series(example_dict)
df = s.explode().rename_axis('Col2').reset_index(name='Col1')

Out[287]:
    Col2 Col1
0    Foo    A
1    Foo    B
2    Foo    C
3    Foo    D
4   Buzz    E
5   Buzz    F
6   Buzz    G
7   Buzz    H
8   Fizz    I
9   Fizz    J
10  Fizz    K
11   Fuu    L
```

**Note**: you may contruct `series` directly from `example_dict`

Comment: worked like a champ. I thought I was onto something with .explode(), but wouldn't have got there without your help. thank you so much!

Comment: @Tommy: you are welcome. I was cautious in splitting `values` and `keys` on series construction. In fact, you can directly pass `example_dict` to construct the series. I edited the answer for that :)