# Creating DataFrame with a double loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I got this:

```
columns = ['a','b','c']
data = [1,2,3],[3,4],[4,5,5]
df = pandas.DataFrame({i:pandas.Series(j) for i in columns for j in data})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  4  4  4
1  5  5  5
2  5  5  5
```

I need:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  3  4
1  2  4  5
2  3     5
```

I really don't understand why this is not working. I know I'm accessing the elements in `data` in the right way.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()
df.columns = columns
```

Output:

```
    a    b    c
0  1.0  3.0  4.0
1  2.0  4.0  5.0
2  3.0  NaN  5.0
```

Comment: Or `pd.DataFrame([data],index=columns).T`

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting values when you enter the second loop.
What you are doing is:

```
import pandas


columns = ['a','b','c']
data = [1,2,3],[3,4],[4,5,5]

myDict = {}
for i in columns:
    for j in data:
        myDict[i]=j
print(pandas.DataFrame(myDict))
```

That's why your data is overwritten. 
What you want to do is clearly:

```
myDict = {}
for i,key in enumerate(columns):
    myDict[key] = data[i]
```

However, this will cause:

```
raise ValueError('arrays must all be same length')
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Which has a well-described solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths)