# Panda Dataframe from Dict with different length value

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe from my dictionary. Each value for the key is actually a array with multiple value in it.

```
>>> my_dict = {"a": [1,2,3], "b": [0], "c": [3,5] }
```

I want all the keys in a column 1 and entire value array in the column 2.

I've tried this post. [Creating dataframe from a dictionary where entries have different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths)

But this solution separates all the value from the key to multiple columns.

Expected DF should look like this

```
>>> df 
      Key_Column   Value_Column
          a            [1,2,3]
          b            [0]
          c            [3,5]
```

Comment: You have an answer that's correct, but I think you should reconsider *why* you want to store data like this.  DataFrames aren't meant to store lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check with `Series`

```
pd.Series(my_dict).rename_axis('Key_Column').reset_index(name='Value_Column')

  Key_Column Value_Column
0          a    [1, 2, 3]
1          b          [0]
2          c       [3, 5]
```

Comment: Right on, thank you so much for the help! I will accept this as the answer after the default 10 mins cool down.