# How to create a Pandas DataFrame from row-based list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data structure like this:

```
data = [{
  "name": "leopard",
  "character": "mean",
  "skills": ["sprinting", "hiding"],
  "pattern": "striped",
 },
 {
  "name": "antilope",
  "character": "good",
  "skills": ["running"],
 },
 .
 .
 .
]
```

Each key in the dictionaries has values of type *integer*, *string* or
*list of strings* (not all keys are in all dicts present), each
dictionary represents a row in a table; all rows are given as the list
of dictionaries.

How can I easily import this into Pandas? I tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

but here I get an "ValueError: arrays must all be same length" error.

Comment: See this question: [Creating dataframe from a dictionary where entries have different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths)

Comment: can post full json? in your current json, it works fine

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Take a look into https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

Comment: @Nihal Sorry, my problem. I had confused two variables I used. Will edit question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataFrame` constructor takes row-based arrays (amoungst other structures) as data input. Therefore the following works:

```
data = [{
  "name": "leopard",
  "character": "mean",
  "skills": ["sprinting", "hiding"],
  "pattern": "striped",
 },
 {
  "name": "antilope",
  "character": "good",
  "skills": ["running"],
 }]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  character      name  pattern               skills
0      mean   leopard  striped  [sprinting, hiding]
1      good  antilope      NaN            [running]
```