# How to convert list of items into pandas columns?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert some categorical values from a `defaultdict(list)` into columns of a pandas dataframe. For example, here is the dict I have:

```
{"user1": ["id1", "id2"], "user2": ["id2", "id3"]}
```

and the expected output is having `user1` and `user2` as rows, and `id1`, `id2`, `id3` as columns and the value is `1` if that `id` appeared in the user's list and `0` otherwise.

I have created a dictionary and use a nested for loop to go through the unique user and ids and create the output but this is really slow. I was wondering what is a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Pandas built-in `from_dict`?

```
data = {"user1": ["id1", "id2"], "user2": ["id2", "id3"]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df
  user1 user2
0   id1   id2
1   id2   id3
```

Or if you want rows:

```
data = {"user1": ["id1", "id2"], "user2": ["id2", "id3"]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

df
         0    1
user2  id2  id3
user1  id1  id2
```

Comment: Thanks but I mean having id1, id2 and id3 as column names? The resulting df has two rows and three columns in this case.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"user1": ["id1", "id2"], "user2": ["id2", "id3"]}

rows = []
cols = [] 

for key, val in data.items() : 
      for v in val :  
        cols.append(v)

cols = list(set(cols)) 

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols) 

print(df)

#rows.append(key)

for key, val in data.items() : 
          row = [] 
          for col in cols : 
            if col not in val : 
              row.append("nan")
             #dft = pd.DataFrame(["NaN"],columns=col)
            else :
              row.append(key)
             #dft = pd.DataFrame([key],columns=col)
          dft = pd.DataFrame([row],columns=cols)


          df = df.append(dft)

df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
print(df)
```

output

```
     id1    id2    id3
0  user1  user1    nan
0    nan  user2  user2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is not entirely clear, but from my understanding here's a solution without loops, in pure pandas. If this is what you are after, I'd recommend viewing the result of each step (provided in multi-line format for easy commenting)

Based on the new information provided in the comments, for a dictionary with different length values (adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths)):

```
d={"user1": ["id1", "id2", "id3"], "user2": ["id2", "id3"], "user3":["id1"]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')    
df
        0   1   2
user1   id1 id2 id3
user2   id2 id3 None
user3   id1 NoneNone

pd.get_dummies(df.unstack())\
.reset_index()\
.drop('level_0', axis=1)\
.groupby('level_1')\
.sum()

        id1 id2 id3
level_1         
user1   1   1   1
user2   0   1   1
user3   1   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks but I should have mentioned in the question.. the number of elements in each list might be different. For example: `{"user1": ["id1", "id2", "id3"], "user2": ["id2", "id3"]}`