# How to add values on specific key on a dictionary that is used as a dataframe in pandas using python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a user input to a key in dictionary that is used as a dataframe but I can't seem to make it to work. Here's what I've done:

```
import pandas as pd

teams = {
  "Team Ahab":["Venom","Quite"],
  "Team Ishmael":[ "Big Boss","EVA"]}

team_df = pd.DataFrame(teams)

user_choice = input("What is your name:")

teams.update({"Team Ahab":user_choice})

team_reader = pd.read_csv("All Teams.txt")
```

When I try to print my dataframe the user input does not come up in the text file that I used since this comes up

```
Team Ahab,Team Ishmael, Team Miller, Team Ocelot 
----------

Venom            John         Kaz       Alex
```

I'm planning on updating the values on the dictionary with the user input(their names) into a key which is their chosen team. Here's what I want to look like

```
user_choice = input("What is your name:") ("Paul")
teams.update({"Team Ahab":user_choice})
print(team_df)
```

My ideal output:

```
Team Ahab ,Team Ishmael, Team Miller, Team Ocelot
Venom            John         Kaz       Alex
Paul
```

Comment: Did you update the dataframe after the input ?  Seems just updated the dict ?

Comment: How  do you update a dataframe again? Sorry I'm new to panda

Comment: What are you trying to do? Because currently you're turning a python `dict` into a dataframe with 2 rows. Then updating the initial python `dict` to replace the list of values with a single string. The writing out csv data to a .txt file from the unmodified dataframe.

Comment: I'm currently making a scoring system for a school that is going to be my project for my programming subject. I'm planning on updating the values on the dictionary with the user input(their names) into a key which is their chosen team. I'm bad at explaining things so please excuse me

Comment: Can you update your question to outline what you are trying to do with sample input and expected output?

Comment: I'll do that now

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary `update()` method overwrites all the old values for the key you pass to it, which is apparently not what you want. To add a name to a team in the dictionary, you could do this instead:

```py
teams["Team Ahab"] += [user_choice]
```

This will update `teams`, but not the DataFrame you want to print, which is `team_df`. You could try to update the DataFrame too, by simply creating it again from the new version of the dictionary:

```py
team_df = pd.DataFrame(teams)
```

But this will not work if the teams now have different numbers of members, because `pd.DataFrame()` requires that all lists of the dictionary (which are to become columns of the DataFrame) have the same length. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths) for a solution.