# converting tuple into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

Assume that we have the following tuple

```
    S=({'country':[('India')],'state':[('Telangana')],'city':[('Hyderabad'),('Vizag')]}, {'date':[{'year': 2021, 'month':10}]})
    
    <class 'tuple'>
```

Can we convert this into a dataframe and get the date part into a variable

```
    df = key      value
         country  India
         state    Telangana
         city     Hyderabad
         city     Vizag
         
    Date = {'date':[{'year': 2021, 'month':10}]}
```

I have tried pd.DataFrame(json.loads(json.dumps(s))) but its not clean

Comment: I don't understand the need for a dataframe here...why not just `S[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

#### For the first part, you can try:

```
pd.Series(S[0]).explode()
```

**Result:**

```
country    India    
state      Telangana
city       Hyderabad
city       Vizag    
dtype: object
```

If you need a dataframe, you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(S[0]).explode().reset_index().values, columns=['key', 'value'])
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

       key      value
0  country      India
1    state  Telangana
2     city  Hyderabad
3     city      Vizag
```

#### For the second part on `Date`, you can use:

```
Date = S[1]
```

**Result:**

```
print(Date)

{'date': [{'year': 2021, 'month': 10}]}
```

Comment: looks good but the result dataframe has braces and commas in the value column            
      key      value
0  country     ( India)
1    state  (Telangana)
2     city  (Hyderabad,)
3     city     ( Vizag,)  how do I remove braces and commas for the value column

Comment: @andy   That's weird.  I tested with your tuple `S` and arrived at the dataframe I shown in the result.  No braces and comma there.   Did you run the code with the tuple `S` given here, or run on another tuple ?

Comment: @andy   Just by dumping `S[0]` on my system gives `{'country': ['India'], 'state': ['Telangana'], 'city': ['Hyderabad', 'Vizag']}`  which already have no braces there.  So, how come the braces come out afterwards ?   Is the tuple that you run contains list of strings instead of list of tuple ?

Comment: @andy  You can also test out using the code: `df = pd.Series(S[0]).explode().to_frame(name='value').rename_axis(index='key').reset_index()` and see how it goes.

Comment: @andy  There is absolutely no reason to get comma in the value column together with the text.  This could happen only when inside your tuple you have something like `'city':['(Hyderabad,)', ' (Vizag,)']`   Note the placement of single quote character `'` is different from that in `S` that you provided.  There probably the braces are inside single quotes as a string.  Please double check with your data.

Answer (score 0):

For the `Date` part, you can try

```py
Date = S[1]
print(Date)
```

```
{'date': [{'year': 2021, 'month': 10}]}
```

As for the first part of your question, you may find the following code less than perfect, but it can easily be edited to match the desired output perfectly.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {k:pd.Series(v) for k, v in dict(S[0]).items()}
).transpose()
print(df)
```

```
               0      1
country      India    NaN
state    Telangana    NaN
city     Hyderabad  Vizag
```

For more information, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths)