# pandas: how to convert list of list into series of list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python, each key has a value of nested lists, like following:

```
test = {'x':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], 'y':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]}
```

and I want to convert the dictionary key into dataframe column names in pandas and the nested lists into series of list, like following:

| 'x' | 'y' |
| --- | --- |
| [1,2,3] | [1,2,3] |
| [4,5,6] | [4,5,6] |

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(test)
print(df)
```

Here is the output in my ide:

[image: Output]

If you want to save the Dataframe into a csv file, you should:

```
output_name = 'myfile.csv'
df.to_csv(output_name)
```

This will create a csv, universal name for excel like files into your working directory.
You can check it's existence with:

```
import os
os.listdir()
```

Comment: Clarification: this can be worked only because `x` and `y` have the same length. `pd.DataFrame({'x':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], 'y':[[1,2,3]]})` raises `ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`

Comment: Correct, in case you need to create a dataframe where dictionary values do have different lenght, refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19736406/15488129

Answer (score 2):

Just convert it to a dataframe, this code returns what you need.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = {'x':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], 'y':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(test)
```

This returns the following:

```
           x          y
0  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]
1  [4, 5, 6]  [4, 5, 6]
```

You can then convert it to a csv file and set the index=False to remove the row numbers(0 and 1 in this case):

```
df.to_csv('df.csv', index=False)
```

That should give you the output as follows:

```
 x          y
[1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]  [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 
 `pd.DataFrame(columns =test.keys() ,data = test.values())`

It resolves the Value error thrown by @girolamo's answer .

For
 `test = {'x':[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], 'y':[[1,2,3]]}`

It gives output :
[image]

That is  if len of x and y are different it returns None