# Converting dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

In the following code, I have defined a dictionary and then converted it to a dataframe

```
my_dict = {
'A' : [1,2],
'B' : [4,5,6]
}
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append(my_dict, ignore_index=True)
```

The output is a [1 rows x 2 columns] dataframe which looks like

```
         A         B
0    [1,2]   [4,5,6]
```

However, I would like to reshape it as

```
     A     B
0    1     4
1    2     5
2          6
```

How can I fix the code for that purpose?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating dataframe from a dictionary where entries have different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, 'index').T
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     A    B
0  1.0  4.0
1  2.0  5.0
2  NaN  6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use [`pandas.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) as follows

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {
'A' : [1,2],
'B' : [4,5,6]
}
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append(my_dict, ignore_index=True)
df = df.apply(lambda x:x.explode(ignore_index=True))
print(df)
```

output

```
     A  B
0    1  4
1    2  5
2  NaN  6
```

I apply explode to each column with `ignore_index=True` which prevent duplicate indices.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the results you are looking for if you don't mind changing your code a little

```
my_dict = {
'A' : [1,2,''],
'B' : [4,5,6]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df
```

Comment: That `''` to make the vectors the same size is a bit tricky. For this example it is fine, but my code has more than two elements and vector lengths are very variable.

Comment: But this can fix the variable lengths https://stackoverflow.com/a/63821093/859227

Comment: would replacing the '' with a np.nan or None work for what you need?

Comment: Yes but as I said, that needs manual modifications to the vectors to make them the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.  you need to assign the dictionary to the dataframe. I've run it.  It should give you the output you desire.  don't use the append.  It's to append one dataframe to another

```
import pandas as pd 

my_dict = {
'A' : [1,2,''],
'B' : [4,5,6]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=my_dict)
#df = df.append(my_dict, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```