# How to create a polars data frame from a dictionary which has unequal length values?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a dictionary as:

```
ex_dict = {'A': ['false',
  'true',
  'false',
  'false',
  'false',
  'true',
  'true',
  'false',
  'false'],
 'B': ['false',
  'false',
  'true',
  'false',
  'false',
  'false'],
  'C': ['false',
  'true',
  'true',
  'false',
  'false',
  'false',
  'false',
  'false',
  'true']}
```

I'm creating a dataframe as:

```
pl.DataFrame(ex_dict)
```

on executing it gives an error as:

```
ShapeError: Could not create a new DataFrame from Series. The Series have different lengths.Got [shape: (9,)
```

How to create a polars dataframe in these scenarios ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place each Series into its own DataFrame, and use a [`concat`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html) with `how="horizontal"`.  This will automatically extend shorter Series with `null` values.

```py
pl.concat(
    items=[pl.DataFrame({_name: _values})
           for _name, _values in ex_dict.items()],
    how="horizontal",
)
```

```
shape: (9, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ A     ┆ B     ┆ C     │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str   ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ false ┆ false ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ true  ┆ false ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ false ┆ true  ┆ true  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ false ┆ false ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ false ┆ false ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ true  ┆ false ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ true  ┆ null  ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ false ┆ null  ┆ false │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ false ┆ null  ┆ true  │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘
```