# Nested dictionary with key: list[key:value] pairs to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently struggling with creating a dataframe based on a dictionary that is nested like `{key1:[{key:value},{key:value}, ...],key2:[{key:value},{key:value},...]}`
And I want this to go into a dataframe, where the value of `key1 and key2` are the index, while the  `list` nested `key:value` pairs would become the `column and record` values.

Now, for each `key1, key2, etc` the list key:value pairs can be different in size. Example data:

```
some_dict = {'0000297386FB11E2A2730050568F1BAB': [{'FILE_ID': '0000297386FB11E2A2730050568F1BAB'},
  {'FileTime': '1362642335'},
  {'Size': '1016439'},
  {'DocType_Code': 'AF3BD580734A77068DD083389AD7FDAF'},
  {'Filenr': 'F682B798EC9481FF031C4C12865AEB9A'},
  {'DateRegistered': 'FAC4F7F9C3217645C518D5AE473DCB1E'},
  {'TITLE': '2096158F036B0F8ACF6F766A9B61A58B'}],
 '000031EA51DA11E397D30050568F1BAB': [{'FILE_ID': '000031EA51DA11E397D30050568F1BAB'},
  {'FileTime': '1384948248'},
  {'Size': '873514'},
  {'DatePosted': '7C6BCB90AC45DA1ED6D1C376FC300E7B'},
  {'DocType_Code': '28F404E9F3C394518AF2FD6A043D3A81'},
  {'Filenr': '13A6A062672A88DE75C4D35917F3C415'},
  {'DateRegistered': '8DD4262899F20DE45F09F22B3107B026'},
  {'Comment': 'AE207D73C9DDB76E1EEAA9241VJGN02'},
  {'TITLE': 'DF96336A6FE08E34C5A94F6A828B4B62'}]}
```

The final result should look like this:

```
Index | File_ID | ... | DatePosted | ... | Comment | Title
0000297386FB11E2A2730050568F1BAB|0000297386FB11E2A2730050568F1BAB|...|NaN|...|NaN|2096158F036B0F8ACF6F766A9B61A58B
000031EA51DA11E397D30050568F1BAB|000031EA51DA11E397D30050568F1BAB|...|7C6BCB90AC45DA1ED6D1C376FC300E7B|...|AE207D73C9DDB76E1EEAA9241VJGN02|DF96336A6FE08E34C5A94F6A828B4B62
```

Now I've tried to parse the dict directly to pandas using comprehension as suggested in [Creating dataframe from a dictionary where entries have different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths) and tried to flatten the dict more, and then parsing it to pandas [Flatten nested dictionaries, compressing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-dictionaries-compressing-keys). Both with no avail.

Comment: have you tried 'from_dict'?
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Comment: Yes, and that results only into a long dataframe, with `[key:value]` pairs as direct input for the records. Resulting in `{'Size': '873514'}` as a row under column X. Only the `key1, key2, keyN` values are transposed as the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

You do not need key of first dict. Because it's also available in lower stages.
Then you need to merge multiple dicts into single one. I did that with update.
THen we turn dict into pd series.
And concat it into a dataframe.

```
In [39]: seriess = []
    ...: for values in some_dict.values():
    ...:     d = {}
    ...:     for thing in values:
    ...:         d.update(thing)
    ...:     s = pd.Series(d)
    ...:     seriess.append(s)
    ...:

In [40]: pd.concat(seriess,axis=1).T
Out[40]:
                            FILE_ID    FileTime     Size  ...                             TITLE                        DatePosted                          Comment
0  0000297386FB11E2A2730050568F1BAB  1362642335  1016439  ...  2096158F036B0F8ACF6F766A9B61A58B                               NaN                              NaN
1  000031EA51DA11E397D30050568F1BAB  1384948248   873514  ...  DF96336A6FE08E34C5A94F6A828B4B62  7C6BCB90AC45DA1ED6D1C376FC300E7B  AE207D73C9DDB76E1EEAA9241VJGN02
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the following code:

```
dfs = []
for k in some_dict.keys():
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame.from_records(some_dict[k]))
    
new_df = [dfs[0].append(x) for x in dfs[1:]][0]

final_result = (new_df
                .groupby(new_df['FILE_ID'].notna().cumsum())
                .first())
```

**Output**

```
    FILE_ID FileTime    Size    DocType_Code    Filenr  DateRegistered  TITLE   DatePosted  Comment
FILE_ID                                 
1   0000297386FB11E2A2730050568F1BAB    1362642335  1016439 AF3BD580734A77068DD083389AD7FDAF    F682B798EC9481FF031C4C12865AEB9A    FAC4F7F9C3217645C518D5AE473DCB1E    2096158F036B0F8ACF6F766A9B61A58B    None    None
2   000031EA51DA11E397D30050568F1BAB    1384948248  873514  28F404E9F3C394518AF2FD6A043D3A81    13A6A062672A88DE75C4D35917F3C415    8DD4262899F20DE45F09F22B3107B026    DF96336A6FE08E34C5A94F6A828B4B62    7C6BCB90AC45DA1ED6D1C376FC300E7B    AE207D73C9DDB76E1EEAA9241VJGN02
```