# How to put the python dictionary in a txt file

Tags: python, arrays, database, dictionary, save

So i'm having serval data store in python dictionary, and I wanted to put them into one .txt file. Does anyone know how i can do that?

Example:

```
dict={'a': array([1,2,3]), 'b': array([10,11,12]), 'c': array([20,21,22])}
```

desired output in txt file:

```
a ,b  ,c
1 ,10 ,20
2 ,11 ,21
3 ,12 ,22
```

Please let me know, really appreciate your help .

I've try using the for loop and the json file type, but still couldn't figure out. I'm new here, so please let me know if need more info, thanks.

Comment: You forgot to post what you tried.

Comment: general advice: don't name your variables as python builtins, ie rename your variable  ```dict``` to something else.

Comment: I think CSV format is what you are looking for.

Comment: Probably the easiest would be to also import pandas and then `pandas.DataFrame(data).to_csv("foo.csv", index=False)` assuming you renamed your variable `dict` to `data`

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72644658/5905029) to a similar question helpful. The idea is simply to serialize the dictionary to a JSON string, then store that string in a file.

More succinctly:

```py
import json

mydict = {'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 7]}

with open('myfile.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(mydict, f)
```

Comment: Where is the conversion to JSON?:

Comment: @user19077881 yeah sorry I screwed up when copy-pasting my code into my original answer. fixed it with an edit just now to use `json.dump` instead of `f.write`

Comment: This will not work with numpy arrays - `TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @ChrisCharley Agreed. If you're working with numpy data you would probably want to look up [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv). Or write your own encoder to serialize the data like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47626762/5905029).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I'm using pandas here to dump to txt file but you can use it to dump as a csv file as well:

```
from numpy import array
dict_ = {'a': array([1,2,3]), 'b': array([10,11,12]), 'c': array([20,21,22])}
import pandas as pd

path = r"abc.txt"
with open(path, 'a') as f:
    df_ = pd.DataFrame(dict_).to_string(header=True, index=False)
    f.write(df_)
```

To dump into a csv instead just use [pd.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also, what if i have different length of the array? Is there any way that I can still save them regardless the length of the array?                                      ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

Comment: See this question for how to do [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths)

Comment: How can i read them back tho? with the same array instead of the string? Really appreciate your help.