# (Norm)ing or equalising a historgram with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, normalization

i have a small favour/question to ask!
I have around 25 of these Images:
[image: images of letters]

And always the same size. I am trying to calculate the amount of black and white space in the image.

[image]

But on some it goes up to 4 and some less, of course!
But I would love to norm it so the z axes always goes up to a fixed number.
I found some ways here: [Plot a histogram such that the total area of the histogram equals 1 (density)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241240/plot-a-histogram-such-that-the-total-area-of-the-histogram-equals-1-density)
But couldn't find the solution I am looking for.
I tried seaboard, change the scale and so on.
code:

```
np.array(pic_b) #letter Picture
pixels_b = np.array(pic_b).flatten()
pixels_b
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 8) )


plt.hist(pixels_b,3, density=True)

# df = sns.load_dataset('penguins') #example data of course 
# fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 6))
# p = sns.histplot(data=df, x='flipper_length_mm', stat='density', ax=ax)


plt.show()
```

Any tips?
Thank you so much, I know I am not very good!

Comment: I highly recommend using seaborn histplot. What you can do is use a weighted histogram. Make a dataframe that precomputes what the bins are, and how much weight goes in each bin, and then divide the weights by the max weight. Then just use stat='count'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) to calculate the histogram values. And then divide the resulting array with its maximum.  `ax.bar(...)` can display the histogram, using the bin boundaries to position the bars:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# first generate some test data
pixels_a = np.random.choice([0, 255], 1000000, p=[0.11, 0.89])
pixels_b = np.random.choice([0, 255], 1000000, p=[0.19, 0.81])
pixels_c = np.random.choice([0, 255], 1000000, p=[0.03, 0.97])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(12, 4))
for data, ax in zip([pixels_a, pixels_b, pixels_c], axs):
    values, bin_bounds = np.histogram(data, bins=3)
    values = values / values.max()
    ax.bar(bin_bounds[:-1], values, width=bin_bounds[1] - bin_bounds[0], align='edge')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram normalized via its maximum]