# normed & stacked options in matplotlib.pyplot.hist

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I have a data set for which I am using hist available in matplotlib.pyplot:

```
In [182]: entries, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(d[w], bins = 50, normed = True, 
                                                 stacked = True)
```

I obtain a histogram instead of probability density which means "normed" or "stacked" does not work.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16399202/42346) will help with the "normed" portion of your question.

Comment: If that fails please include in your question a self-contained runnable example that we can test, thank you.