# Plotting a probability distribution using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, softmax

I would like to plot the softmax probabilities for a neural network classification task, similar to the plot below

However most of the code I've found on `SO` and the doc pages for `matplotlib` are using histograms.

Examples:

[plotting histograms whose bar heights sum to 1 in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866520/plotting-histograms-whose-bar-heights-sum-to-1-in-matplotlib)

[Python: matplotlib - probability mass function as histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889444/python-matplotlib-probability-mass-function-as-histogram)

http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

But none of them match what I'm trying to achieve in that plot. Code and sample figure are highly appreciated.

[image: example softmax plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are just looking for a different plot type. Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889444/python-matplotlib-probability-mass-function-as-histogram):

```
# Import 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random normally distributed data
data=np.random.randn(10000)

# Histogram
heights,bins = np.histogram(data,bins=50)

# Normalize
heights = heights/float(sum(heights))
binMids=bins[:-1]+np.diff(bins)/2.
plt.plot(binMids,heights)
```

Which produces something like this:

[image]

Hope that is what you are looking for.