# matplotlib.pyplot.hist wrong normed property

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I am creating histograms of data organized in a dataframe and grouped by days. It might happen that in some days the data is identically null. Therefore, when I plot the histogram using the `normed = True` property, I would expect one single bin centered in zero and with height equal to 1. However, I see that the height is equal to the number of bins. How can I fix this? I want to represent a probability density function with the histogram, so the maximum value should be 1.

Code sample and output:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 4
data = np.zeros((1000))
l = plt.hist(data,normed = True, bins = 100)
```

[image]

**EDIT**: I saw now that the property `normed` is deprecated. However, if I try to use the attribute `density`, I get the error `AttributeError: Unknown property density`

Comment: Specifiaclly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16399202/5851928) answer of the duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plot you see is correct because the area under the curve (histogram/bar) should be 1. This is indeed the case in your plot. To highlight this, I create a vertical line at `x=0.01` and you will notice that the width of the bar is indeed 0.01. Since the height of the bar is 100, the area is 100 * 0.01 = 1.

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 4
data = np.zeros((1000))
l = plt.hist(data,normed = True, bins = 100)
plt.axvline(0.01, lw=1)
plt.ylim(0, 150)
```

The same happens if you use `density=True` as

```
l = plt.hist(data,density = True, bins = 100)
```

[image]

Using the suggestion of [jdehesa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782792/jdehesa), following works your way

```
l = plt.hist(data,density = True, bins=np.arange(-10, 11))
```

[image]

Using the suggestion of [DavidG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5851928/davidg) based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866520/plotting-histograms-whose-bar-heights-sum-to-1-in-matplotlib/16399202#16399202) answer gives you a height of 1 but the area is not normalized to 1.

```
weights = np.ones_like(data)/float(len(data))
l = plt.hist(data,weights=weights)
```

[image]

Finally, if you need a height of 1 and a width of 1 (hence area = 1) and also the normalized area, you can use a single bin as

```
l = plt.hist(data, density=True, bins=1)
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As other have explained, `normed=True` (or `density=True` in recent versions of Matplotlib) makes the area under the histogram equal to 1. You can get a histogram that represents the fraction of the sample falling on each bin like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.zeros((1000))
# Compute histogram
hist, bins = np.histogram(data, density=True, bins=100)
# Width of each bin
bins_w = np.diff(bins)
# Compute proportion of sample in each bin
hist_p = hist * bins_w
# Plot histogram
plt.bar(bins[:-1], hist_p, width=bins_w, align='edge')
```

Result:

[image: Histogram of fractions]

You could also make a histogram where each bin has a width of 1, but that is a more limited solution.

EDIT: As pointed out in other answers, this is basically equivalent to giving the proper `weights` parameter to `plt.hist`.