# Matplotlib histogram not showing probability densities on y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of data log10(LR), that I will like to show the distribution of in a histogram.

I am using `plt.hist` from `matplotlib` to present the data.

However, it is showing the y axis as a max of 3.5 and I can't figure out why.

```
bins = np.linspace(-2, 3, 30)
plt.hist (y, bins, label=['M', 'CNM'], density= True, align= 'mid')
plt.title('Calibrated Likelihood Ratio for 6 minutiae')
plt.xlabel('log10(LRk)')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image: Output of the code]

I have included an image of the code output.
I would like to know what I am missing from this plot, thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think that there's something wrong with the plot? 3.5 is a perfectly fine value for a *probability density*.

Comment: This seems to be a misinterpretation of the chart. The bar with height 3.6 tells you that the probability to find a value between `-1.138` and `-0.966` is `(-0.966 + 1.138)*3.6 = 0.62 = 62%`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest okay thank you. so I need it to be displaying the 0.62 value on the y-axis, do you know what my code is missing to achieve this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866520/plotting-histograms-whose-bar-heights-sum-to-1-in-matplotlib